# Jar crashes while decrypting AES encrypted Authorization token method in code. hs_err _pid file mentions arrayof_jbyte_fill

Tags: java, spring, encryption, cryptography, aes

This issue occurs around once in a day on the production environment. The load is around 20TPS and the AES decryption is called twice for every request on the server. The error is not generated for all requests but It crashes once in a day. Following is the snippet of hs_err_pid file.

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

**SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f26cc5de47e, pid=53978, tid=0x00007f26837f7700**
JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_241-b31) (build 1.8.0_241-b31)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.241-b31 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
**Problematic frame:**
**v  ~StubRoutines::arrayof_jbyte_fill**

```
Current thread (0x00007f26d0a03800):  JavaThread "http-nio-9094-exec-10" daemon 
[_thread_in_Java, id=54617, stack(0x00007f26836f7000,0x00007f26837f8000)]


Stack: [0x00007f26836f7000,0x00007f26837f8000],  sp=0x00007f26837f44f0,  free space=1013k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
v  ~StubRoutines::arrayof_jbyte_fill
J 26458 C2 java.util.Arrays.fill([BB)V (21 bytes) @ 0x00007f26cc737ca2 
[0x00007f26cc737c60+0x42]
j  com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer([BI[BII[B)I+73
j  com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal([BII)[B+65
j  com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal([BII)[B+7
j  javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal([B)[B+30
j  com.hello.genesys.common.AES.decrypt([BLjava/lang/String;)[B+92
```

Following is the decryption method :

```
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] data, String password) throws Exception {
    try {
        log.info("/// Inside the decrypter method of AES class ////");
        if (null == cipher) {
            log.info("The Cipher is null and hence forming new object of cipher");
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
        }

        log.info("Key generation method to be called");
        Key k = new SecretKeySpec(password.getBytes(), AES_ENCRYPTION_TYPE);
        
        log.info("Cipher initialization to be done");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);

        log.info("The byte array value to be returned");
        
        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        log.info("Inside Exception of AES decryption method");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This method is called in a different class :

```
byte[] decrypter = AES.decrypt(decodeToken, _env("tokenSalt"));
```

It does not throws an exception but crashes with **arrayof_jbyte_fill** related error. Please help me solve this issue as it occurs only in the production environment but not in a lower environment. Link to the hs_err_pid file for more details: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WDG4rm7vIw6HDbhZPtXjud7r8TEh4d74/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That code appears to have been refactored in 8u201 and 11.0.2 up, and among other things the Array.fill added (conditionally, in the finally clause), which should not be executing on doFinal for decrypt (your case) -- and it definitely shouldn't SEGV. Is this server mulithtreaded and if so is there any possibility of unprotected contention on this Cipher object? If the performance is not too bad, you might try running with `-Xint` and see if you get an exception instead of a fault, or at least something more informative.

Comment: PS: something called a password that can be represented in a String is usually insecure, though something called a salt might not be; so is ECB for most data. But those are unrelated to your crash, and probably offtopic for SO.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 So the cipher object is initialized globally in that class which has encrypt and decrypt methods. So I am deciding to initialize the object inside the method itself to avoid collision of resource between two threads. I was even thinking of trying object pooling but have made the object local for now rather than global. What say?

Comment: Probably worth a try, although creating JCA objects tends to be expensive and doing it frequently may affect performance. That said, debugging multithread problems is usually hard, often impossible, so spending some cost to avoid them is often a good tradeoff. Of course I'm only guessing this _is_ multithread; it _could_ be something else.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Glad to inform that the issue is resolved. The goof-up was with the cipher object itself. I have created & initialized a local cipher object instead of the global one and there seems to be no crash for 2 weeks after deployment. So as 2 decryption processes were occurring simultaneously back to back, it was getting crashed during the second decryption request as the object was still being used by one. So this is my analysis for this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goof-up was with the cipher object itself. I have now created & initialized a local cipher object instead of the global one and there seems to be no crash for 2 weeks after deployment. So as 2 decryption processes were occurring simultaneously back to back, it was getting crashed during the second decryption request as the object was still being used by the first one. So this is my analysis for this issue